# How to show ad after closing the app in iOS?

Tags: ios, admob

Please let me know how to show the ad(AdMob) after closing the app in the iOS?, I know that ad can be shown in the opened app, and I searched on the web I couldn't find it.

Comment: AdMob rules will not allow this scanerio. Also your app can be reject from Apple. But if you want, you can call in - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application methon in your AppDelegate.

Comment: Thanks @EmreGürses, could it be possible to use another ad provider with same functionality?

Comment: Which one? Could you give me name. You should read add provider policy before add this code. Because your admob account can be banned.

Comment: Can use double click?

Comment: Whats your mean "double click"?

Comment: Double click adwords

Comment: @EmreGürses , this is not possible. iOS will not show this banner.

Comment: @Vyacheslav  Yes it is possible. Because GopalDevra not mention add type. So, Interstitial add can be added but it is not recomended

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not allowed. From [Disallowed interstitial implementations](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362?hl=en&ref_topic=2745287):

> **App load or exit**
>
> Do not place interstitial ads on app load and when exiting apps as
>   interstitials should only be placed in between pages of app content.
>   Ads should not be placed in applications that are running in the
>   background of the device or outside of the app environment. It should
>   be clear to the user which application the ad is associated with or
>   implemented on.